# How to crop each page of a PDF individually?

Tags: pdf

How can I automatically trim margins of a multi-page PDF via Linux command line such that each PDF page gets cropped individually? http://pdfcrop.sourceforge.net/ does not do the job as confirmed by https://onetransistor.blogspot.de/2016/01/pdf-crop-linux-software.html I am on Kubuntu 14.4.

Comment: On that page I don't see that pdfcrop "does not do the job".

Comment: @GerardH.Pille: It says "There is no way to select page range or apply different crop boxes to different pages."

Answer (score 0):

PDF CPU is a good option:

```
pdfcpu crop -pages -3,5,7- '0 0 17' in.pdf out.pdf
```

https://pdfcpu.io/core/crop